# Write a Java program that shows a simple CookiePolicy that blocks cookies from .gov domains, but allows others

Tags: java, cookies

```
import java.net.CookiePolicy;
import java.net.HttpCookie;
import java.net.URI;

public class NoGovernmentCookies implements CookiePolicy {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldAccept(URI uri, HttpCookie cookie){
        if(uri.getAuthority().toLowerCase().endsWith(".gov")){
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

I have made new CookieTest class to call NoGovernmentCookies.

```
import java.net.*;
import java.util.List;

public class CookieTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        CookieManager manager = new CookieManager();


        HttpCookie c1 = new HttpCookie("user1", "1");
        URI uri1 = URI.create("http://spm.gov");



        manager.setCookiePolicy(new NoGovernmentCookies());

      /*  manager.setCookiePolicy(CookiePolicy.ACCEPT_ALL);
        manager.setCookiePolicy(CookiePolicy.ACCEPT_NONE);
        manager.setCookiePolicy(CookiePolicy.ACCEPT_ORIGINAL_SERVER);*/

       // CookieHandler.setDefault(manager);
        CookieStore cs = manager.getCookieStore();
        cs. add(uri1, c1);


        //read stored cookies
        List cl = cs.getCookies();
        System.out.println("cookies list in cookiestore" + cl + "\n");
    }

}
```

it is showing output as value:

```
cookies list in cookiestore[user1="1"]
```

I do not want to add it in cookiestore, because it is against our  NoGovernmentCookies policy for `.gov`.

Comment: What is your exact question?

Comment: @PM77-1 it should not store cookie 'c1' value because it is an .gov.

Comment: I have edited the bottom of your question. If I did not get it right - please [Edit] it for further clarification.

Comment: It is the `CookieManager` that has a `CookiePolicy`, not the `CookieStore`. The store just does what you tell it to do. Try via `CookieManager.put()`, or better still install the cookie manager and try via a real .gov URL.

Comment: NB There is no [tag:spring] here. nor any [tag:collections], nor (so far) any [tag:network-programming] either. Don't tag indiscriminately.